# How to write a CSV file so it is read by csv.DictReader() as string/int?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, export-to-csv

I use `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()` to write a DataFrame to a CSV file. In this file, one of the columns represents "Year". The problem is that, when the CSV file is loaded by using `csv.DictReader()`, this column is apparently being read as a float number and, hence, `.0` is added to its value!! The following is the exact reading line:

`csvfile = csv.DictReader(of, delimiter="|")`

I double checked the saved CSV file and there is not decimal points there at all!

How to properly write a CSV file so certain columns are read by `csv.DictReader()` as string or at least as intergers?

**Note**: I have no control on how the `csv.DictReader()` will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check what type is `Year` column with:

```
df['Year'].dtype
```

if it's of type `float64` than you should convert it to integers:

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(int)
```

Unless you have empty cells in that row, then you need to fill them in first (because you cannot have `NaN`'s in integer columns):

```
df['Year'].fillna(1234)
```

Alternatively, play with parameter `float_format` for `to_csv()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The `dtype` is `int32` and, still, after reading lines by using `csv.DictReader()`, the `line['Year']` becomes float !!! Also, all the `Year` values stored in the `CSV` file are integers.

Comment: Although it turned out my problem was somewhere else, I think this is the solution if the problem was indeed as I described in the question.